# Kubernetes runAsNonRoot failing: CreateContainerConfigError

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have added a security context in my pod which looks as follows:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: true
```

While running the pod I am getting error message (kubectl get pod pod-name -o=yaml):

> container has runAsNonRoot and image has non-numeric user (default),
>             cannot verify user is non-root

The message is intuitive but, after reading this [kubernetes blog](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/08/security-best-practices-kubernetes-deployment/) it seems to me it should be very straight forward, what I am missing here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error comes only when your uid == nil,. Based on the error text, we need to set a numeric user value.

So, for the user with UID=1000 you can do it in your pod definition like:

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 1000
```

So your `securityContext` should be like:

```
securityContext:
  fsGroup: 2000
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1000
```

Checkout it in official docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod)

Comment: but the pod should have the user with `UID` 999?

Comment: also I did saw this property `spec:
  runAsUser:
    rule: MustRunAsNonRoot` will this help to run container as non-root?

Comment: This is the linux user uid. If you want to run pod as a centos user in your linux system, you need to provide uid of centos user. You can find uid using `id -u <user_name>`

Comment: yes, I am using centos, if you mean to login into `pod` and get the user id then it won't be feasible I am using HELM to provide the securityContext and at the moment of deployment I don't know if the `pod` will have that user id or not.

Comment: but seems like `MustRunAsNonRoot` works. as per the code of `kubernetes` https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/policy/types.go#L368

Comment: But you still need to provide the uid. Could you please replace the security context in my answer to your pod spec. It should work. UID=1000 shows that you want to run as non root with uid 1000.

Comment: yup, I did that, and it worked. Thought I am thinking whats the difference between running as `MustRunAsNonRoot` (as in my answer) and `runAsNonRoot: true`

Comment: This is what official doc says `MustRunAsNonRoot - Requires that the pod be submitted with a non-zero runAsUser or have the USER directive defined (using a numeric UID) in the image. No default provided. Setting allowPrivilegeEscalation=false is strongly recommended with this strategy.`

Comment: An interesting link to go over https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/secure-kubernetes-cluster-psp/ Hope this clarifies some fog over it :)

Comment: Thanks Prafull, that link was helpful, I understand from the link that image should have a user that is non-root, and that is restricted by providing `MustRunAsNonRoot`

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to the Dockerfile solved my issue

```
USER 9000:9000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the securityContext as follows:

```
spec:
  runAsUser:
    rule: MustRunAsNonRoot
  containers:
    - name: <container-name>
```

This can be confirmed with [Kubernetes code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/policy/types.go#L368)

Comment: This is not the `securityContext` but a `PodSecurityPolicy` that you are referring to. Did this solve your problem?

Comment: not really, it disabled privilege escalation but not sure if the container was running as non-root user.