# CreateContainerConfigError: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root

Tags: kubernetes

working with rancher below types of issue comes ---please help me for exacted code
App: influxdb2Installing
Failed to install app influxdb2. Error: failed post-install: job failed: DeadlineExceeded

CreateContainerConfigError: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root

Regards
Praveen

Comment: Seems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720308/kubernetes-podsecuritypolicy-set-to-runasnonroot-container-has-runasnonroot-and can help you

Comment: Does the above solve your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kubernetes PodSecurityPolicy set to runAsNonRoot, container has runAsNonRoot and image has non-numeric user (appuser), cannot verify user is non-root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720308/kubernetes-podsecuritypolicy-set-to-runasnonroot-container-has-runasnonroot-and)

Answer (score 0):

Add to the pod definition:

```
securityContext:
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1000
```

Also check this answer for more details:
[Kubernetes runAsNonRoot failing: CreateContainerConfigError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949329/kubernetes-runasnonroot-failing-createcontainerconfigerror)

Comment: that's exactly what is causing the issue. You need to add `runAsUser` and as bonus `runAsGroup` to the `securityContext`. Or even better create a user in your container and use its uid as `USER` instruction, that way kubernetes is able to see its a non root user.

Comment: Yeah, this was missing: `runAsUser: 1000`